# Conversion failed

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to add some parameter to a table and I get this error in the Visual Studio 2013. I'm having trouble with Date & Time. My date & time datatypes used in SQL Server 2008 R2 are `Date` and `Time(7)`. I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

What is my mistake?

My code:

```
string strquery = "select count(*) from SaloonGeneralReservation where SaloonReservationDate=@SaloonReservationDate";

    SqlConnection connection2 = DBConnection.getConnection();
    connection2.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
    cmd2.Connection = connection2;
    cmd2.CommandText = strquery;

    cmd2.Parameters.Add("@SaloonReservationDate", txt1_date.Text);


    int intRowCount = (int) cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
    txt1_date.Text = intRowCount.ToString();
    connection2.Close();


    if (intRowCount == 1)
    {
        Messages myMsg = new Messages(); // ایجاد نمونه از کلاس
        myMsg.CreateMessageAlert("سالن در این تاریخ رزرو شده است . لطفا تاریخ دیگری وارد نمایید.");
        txt1_date.Text = "";

         }


    else
    {
        string strQuery = "INSERT INTO [WeedingSalonGeneralRes](Date,Time,Fruit,Drink,Desert,MainFood,Salad,TableFlower,SaloonLighting,Saloondesign,SloonCrew,Pastry,GiftCard,customer_id)" + "VALUES(@Date,@Time,@Fruit,@Drink,@Desert,@MainFood,@Salad,@TableFlower,@SaloonLighting,@Saloondesign,@SloonCrew,@Pastry,@GiftCard,@customer_id)";


        SqlConnection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandText = strQuery;


        string cis = Session["customerID"].ToString();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", txt1_date.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Time", txt2_time.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Fruit", fruit);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Drink", drink);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Desert", desert);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@MainFood", mainfood);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Salad", salad);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TableFlower", tableflower);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SaloonLighting", saloonlighting);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Saloondesign", saloondesing);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SloonCrew", salooncrew);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pastry", pastry);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@GiftCard", giftcard);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@customer_id", cis);


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
        Response.Redirect("ReservationSucces.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Please  provide an example of the dates amd times in your question.  And what is your current locale for the database - a mismatched locale is a common cuase of errors when dealing with dates

Comment: this is my date input format 2016-10-10 and this is my time 10:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `TIME(7)` needs to be `HH:MM:SS` at a minimum, and `HH:MM:SS.NNNNNNN` maximum. So, add `:00` on your string for your `TIME` to make the conversion work. The `DATE` should be fine as long as you are using `YYYY-MM-DD`. You WILL get this error if you are using `YYYY-DD-MM`.

Comment: for example i try this time 10:00:00 and again i have that error

Comment: Assuming you are using `YYYY-MM-DD` for your `DATE` then the error must be in `txt1_date.Text`

Comment: this is my all code , i check a condtition in the first query  . if i have a date LooksLike in the txt1_date.text i give a error to my client and if that date is Not available in the database the client date & ....will be insert in the table . Please see my updated Codes at the Top of Page.

Comment: You are trying to use a `rowcount` as a `DATE` here `txt1_date.Text = intRowCount.ToString()` so you aren't inserting a `DATE`

Comment: ok ,but What code  should I use? do you know a code for this Problem?

Comment: comment out `txt1_date.Text = intRowCount.ToString();`

Comment: sorry i was sick last week & i cant test that ,i test now and That work Correctly . Thank you